# Call Lua function from C++, missing argument

Tags: c++, lua, arguments, argument-passing

I have strange problem, with calling Lua function from C++.
I have in Lua:

```
Player = 
{
    Number = 0.43,
    Text = "SomeText",
}

function Player:Func(a, b)  
    return (a * b);
end
```

Before lua_pcall my stack looks:
table
function
3
4

I call this function with:

```
lua_pcall(L, 2, 1, 0)
```

And I get error from Lua:

> attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'b' (a nil value)

When I change in Lua script

```
return (a * b);
```

to

```
return a;
```

There is no error, but from lua_tonumber(L, -1); I get value 4 (my second argument in C:/), so it looks that my second argument in C is first in Lua.
Do you know what I made wrong in my code ?

How I construct stack:

```
lua_getglobal (L, "Player");
lua_pushstring(L, "Func");
lua_gettable(L, -2);
lua_pushnumber(L, 3.0);
lua_pushnumber(L, 4.0);
```

Comment: Obviously your stack is not what you think it is. So why don't you show us the code that sets up the stack?

Comment: Do you maybe need to push a hidden `this` pointer (or Lua equivalent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ben's comment is the key - Read the Object-oriented programming section in "Programming In Lua", page 150.

http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html

> The effect of the colon is to add an extra hidden parameter in a
>   method definition and to add an extra argument in a method call.

So you need to push an "Account" object as the first parameter, or (more easily in this case) change `function Player:Func(a, b)` to `function Player.Func(a, b)`